# addressing the same column twice with different criteria in linest function

Tags: excel, regression

pretty much an excel newbie so I hope you bear with me. Here is my regression equation:

```
Rp-Rf = a + b*(Rm - Rf) + c*max(0,Rm-Rf)
```

I have the `Rp-Rf (C61:C114)` data in one column and `Rm-Rf (X61:X114)` data in one column. I want to do a regression with the LINEST function, without creating another column for max(0,Rm-Rf) data. Maybe something like:

```
=LINEST(C61:C114;X61:X114\max(X61:X114);;FALSE)
```

Is it possible? Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question well, but why don't you just type in the formula and see if it works?

Comment: It didn't work :) The thing is, if I created another Y column with the max(0,Rm-Rf) values, =LINEST(C61:C114;X61:Y114) would work. But I want to be able to do it without creating that extra column.

Comment: Try your formula but instead of Enter when exiting edit mode use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  This is a long shot but may work as an array formula.